# Trying to install gcc on ubuntu amazon EC2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to install gcc and g++ compiler on my amazon ec2 instance. but when i type the command on the instance

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

I got stuck when I try to connect the amazon archives. I wait here a little bit:

```
0% [Connecting to us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com (54.231.160.74)]
```

and then get a bunch of errors about not being able to connect to the archives. Does anyone know the solution? Thanks.

Errors:

```
Err http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libasan0 i386 4.8.2-19ubuntu1
Could not connect to us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (54.231.160.74), connection timed out


E: Failed to fetch http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc6-dev_2.19-0ubuntu6_i386.deb  Unable to connect to us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amazon ec2 ubuntu installing gcc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26695438/amazon-ec2-ubuntu-installing-gcc)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay got the answer, I needed to arrange the outbound rules for my security group.

[image]

Comment: Could you add more details? Having the same problem. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, it was a while ago. but if i'm not mistaken it was about the rules of my security group. go to amazon ec2 management console, from the left banner, go to security groups section. Then click the one that has your instance is running on. On the bottom, click the outbound. Make sure you add Type: SSH / Protocol: TCP / Port Range: 22 to both inbound and outbound. Also, select the source to be anywhere, not your ip or custom ip. Please let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Keep the settings as shown in above picture and it will resolve the issue.