# Amazon ec2 ubuntu installing gcc

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to install gcc on ec2 instance with ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

gives me:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Err http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-libc-dev amd64 3.13.0-36.63
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main linux-libc-dev amd64 3.13.0-36.63
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_3.13.0-36.63_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`sudo apt-get update` fixed the problem.